# how do disable the focus in javascript fancytree

Tags: fancytree

I have found a way to disable the activation when an item is clicked by canceling its processing with beforeactivate. I would also like to disable the focus. The thin square around the item focused. Is there a way to do it in javascript, or shall I aim for the CSS directly ?

Many thanks,

M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the same problem through CSS:

```
.fancytree-container,
span.fancytree-focused span.fancytree-title
{
    outline: 0 !important;
}
```